# A simple for-loop with openMP in C

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a for loop in the following code.

```
int min = -1;
int pos;
int array[100];

for(i = 0; i < 100; i++){
  if(array[i] < min || min == -1){
    min = array[i];
    pos = i;
  }
}
```

I think that the following code is a correct implementation with openMP but it is too slow.

```
int min = -1;
int pos;
int array[100];

#pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(array, min) 
for(i = 0; i < 100; i++){
#pragma omp critical
  {
    if(array[i] < min || min == -1){
      min = array[i];
      pos = i;
    }
  }
}
```

I think that could be data hazards if i put the critical section inside the condition instead of outside. There is a smart way to implement it? Some suggestions?

Comment: `min = -1` shouldn't this be `min == -1`?

Comment: correct this portion.. if(array[i] < min || min = -1)

Comment: You can try to run parallel, say `quicksort`, and on every reduction save also the original index of min element in sub-collection.

Comment: If the whole body of the loop is a critical section, the parallel pragma is completely useless.

Comment: @ketul corrected it.

Comment: @EOF
It's worst than serial implementation, but with larger arrays the possibility to satisfy the condition is low. Initially I wanted to use some other variable to prevent the access to min in order to avoid data hazard. But i was not able to do it.

Comment: @Tigran
Can you explain better?

Comment: Run `quicksort` in parallel (divide and conquer) , on every sub-segment sort by ascending, and save the original index of smaller element. after sorting every single segment, as by design of `quicksort`, merge and sort segments, again by saving the smallest element original index.

Comment: @Tigran
I don't know if I understand well what you say. You suggest to save all positions that verifies the condition and then analyze them a posteriori to find the smallest one?

Comment: Of course it's worse than the serial implementation. It *is* serial, but adds thread creation and synchronisation overhead. Do you really think creating a new thread is faster than reading 100 `int`s? You might start to see speed up *if* you properly parallelized the loop *and* used it on a *much* larger array.

Comment: @Search for "paralle quicksort" implementation. The onlt difference in your case, imo, would be that instead only sorting them you have to save somewhere original index of smaller element found in every segment and after sort in entire collection. Sort and get original index the smaller element, basically [0] after sorting, but with save somewhere index of where that element was moved from.

Comment: @Tigran: Why are you so hung up about `quicksort()`? This code doesn't sort, it just finds the minimum. Finding the minimum is O(n), quicksort is O(nlogn).

Comment: @EOF: quicksort is just an option, the idea is "divide conquer" so easily parallelize, remaining in context of the question asked. divide and conquer to avoid dependency between calculus as much as possible for *successful parallelisation*. If you are not going parallel this, there are simpler solutions, but they may result in too slow execution on big collections.

Comment: @EOF
I use it with larger array. Obviously it is not time convenient use this implementation. I'm looking for suggestion, i don't have the solution.
For now, i use the critical inside the condition, is faster than the serial implementation thanks to the fact that the condition it is not verified often. I can do it without error because a lot of elements have the same minimum value. But i cannot say for sure that i cannot have errors.

Comment: @Tigran: You you really suggesting that it is necessary to do a `quicksort()` in order to divide and conquer a linear search? You *do* realize that the linear search is trivial to parallelize, as it never modifies the array?

Comment: @EOF: if you have a better answer/solution, write it on the box bellow and submit it to OP.

Comment: @Tigran I don't need to sort the array. I mean, it's only an array to store elements that often are extract or put into it. I don't want to transform a problem of searching in a problem of sorting without benefits. I don't think that is possible to have any in this case.

Comment: @Tigran: Done. Tell me if you find anything wrong with it.

Comment: @EOF: concept looks reasonable. The only problem I see is the recursion, which is not where OpenMP really shines, so this code a part of fitting to concrete working implementation has to be yet tested in terms of performance. If op has an option of using TBB, that would be much better, or if he rewrites this code without using a recursion but using map-reduce flow.

Comment: @Tigran: Sure, it's not ideal. `MINDIVIDE` needs to be empirically optimized, and for large arrays it may create too many threads. Really, it might be better to avoid recursion and create as many threads as the hardware supports right away. But *that* is probably a bad idea on really large machines (~1000nds of cores), when you *already have* parallelism. Either way, I believe the answer is good enough for this question.

Comment: @Tigran
I don't know TBB. I'm googled it and seems only valid in C++. I need to implement the function in C.

Comment: @EOF: OpenMP, like a library doesn't really handles well nested tasks, that what I meant by talking about "recursion problem". The control of working threads pool on concrete machine is another discussion, and goes slightly ahead..

Comment: @giusva: so look on the answer and change according to your needs.

Comment: @Tigran: Yeah, my answer kinda abuses openMP as a `fork()`, but if I used `fork()` directly, I'd have to implement a thread pool, and that *really* exceeds the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've coded up a small parallel search function. I've only tested that it compiles, but I believe the principle is sound:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#define MINDIVIDE 1024

int parallelminsearch(int const *array, size_t size)
{
  int minimum;
  if (size < MINDIVIDE)
    {
      minimum = array[0];
      for (size_t i = 1; i < size; i++)
        {
          if (array[i] < minimum)
          minimum = array[i];
        }
      return minimum;
    }
  int pmin[2];
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
      pmin[i] = parallelminsearch(&array[i*size/2], (size+1)/2);
    }
  minimum = (pmin[0] < pmin[1])?pmin[0]:pmin[1];
  return minimum;
}
```